# Error when I submit my build to the app store

Tags: ios, react-native, icons, app-store

When I try to submit my build to the apple app store I get the error "Your iOS app icon is missing or is an invalid format. The icon must be a 1024x1024 PNG image with no transparency." when I run 'eas submit --platform ios  ' to submit my react-native ios app build. I also tried to upload the build with Transport and get the same error:
[image]

The app icon is 1024 x 1024 .png and app.json points to that file.
[image]

Here is my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "acme",
    "name": "job_it",
    "slug": "job_it",
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ],
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/Peace3.png",
      "color": "#000000",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/Peace3.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/Peace2Small1024.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/Peace3.png",
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.jwin.ios",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleIconName": "Peace3",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Search for jobs and go to the application page right from the app!",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "This app does not require location access to function properly.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "This app does not require constant location access to function properly."
      }
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "2fe8412c-0a6c-4ccc-b2a5-131ec4b8f44c"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.jwin.ios"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to jpg and no more transparency issues